# SplitDateTimeField default value is not localized

Tags: python, django

So I have this field in a form:

```
date_time = forms.SplitDateTimeField(required=False, localize=True,
                                         label=_("Change the date and time"),
                                         )
```

and initially, the page looks like this:

[image: photo1]

even though I have localize set to True.
After I select another date from the datepicker, the date will be localized properly.
[image: photo2]

I'd like the date to be localized from the start. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: This is just a guess, but have you tried setting "initial=" value to it? For example initial="LOCAL_TIME_HERE". So that it would be initialized with local date from the start.

Comment: @axordahaxor I tried it this way: initial=datetime.now() It still doesn't work.